# Cambiar el orden en que se muestra los menus en android studio

Tags: android

esto se me esta haciendo cuesta arriba, a ver si me podeis ayudar con este problema, al menos para mi.
Tengo creado un menu con estas opciones:

```js
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new menu1();
            case 1:
                return new menu2();
            case 2:
                return new menu3();
            case 3:
                return new menu4();
            case 4:
                return new menu5();
            case 5:
                return new menu6();
            case 6:
                return new menu7();
            case 7:
                return new menu8();
            case 8:
                return new menu9();
            case 9:
                return new menu10();
            case 10:
                return new menu11();
            default:
                return new menu1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 11;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "menu1";
            case 1:
                return "menu2";
            case 2:
                return "menu3";
            case 3:
                return "menu4";
            case 4:
                return "menu5";
            case 5:
                return "menu6";
            case 6:
                return "menu7";
            case 7:
                return "menu8";
            case 8:
                return "menu9";
            case 9:
                return "menu10";
            case 10:
                return "menu11";
            default:
                return "menu1";
        }
    }
}
```

Y muestra el menu1 se queda en el lado izquierdo de la pantalla, como puedo cambiar el orden, que el muestre el menu1 pero que en el menus se muestre de derecha a izquierda ?

este es el codigo que tengo en activity_main.xml

```js
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: el menu1 se agrega a la izquierda de que ? tienes el layout? puedes poner el layout y mostrar una imagen de como se ve?

Comment: Hola, a la izquierda en la barra del menu, se muestra asi:  
http://s018.radikal.ru/i506/1712/54/d9b3160cacfa.png  

intento que el Menu1 se muestre en el lado derecho de la barra del menu, y que muestre seleccionado.

Comment: @SoCu en este caso debes agregar el código de tu Adapter.

Comment: @Jorgesys creo que me he perdido, ahora viene la pregunta tonta, que código y dónde?  si es muy complicado de explicar lo dejamos, no quiero molestar más de la cuenta, porque me he metido de lleno con un proyecto que me dejaron a medias, y son sin saber programar ni inglés, voy dando palos de ciego, intentando ver y probando códigos, y entender los manuales que veo, para terminar el menú y poder enlazar con las páginas web.

Comment: @SoCu no te preocupes aquí obtendrás la ayuda requerida, pero es importante realizar la pregunta con la información necesaria. Agrega tu clase SectionPagerAdapter  y también como la llamas.

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo que quieres es que ponga aquí en el post el código completo ?  
    
Este proyecto muestra dos menús, uno de ellos es éste, una pregunta, a este tipo de menús se le puede poner un submenú para que cuando se pulse un menú muestre el submenú ?  


 He intentado buscar tu dirección de correo, se puede ver aquí en el foro ?

Comment: Tu "submenu" lo puedes agregar dentro de cada fragment ...

Comment: Hola @AshleyG.perdono por no responder antes, no recibo notificaciones por correo de nuevas respuestas y despues de estar entrando varios dias pensaba que habia quedado avandonado este post, porque tu respuesta no la he llegado a ver, el tema de cambiar el menu de sitio ya lo he dejado, pero lo de crear un submenu lo sigo intentando, por lo que he visto si creo un submenu en un fragment no saldria unido al menu de arriba, no? de no ser asi, si puedes poner algo de codigo que pueda hacerlo te lo agradeceria.